# Websphere Basic Authentication doesn't work

Tags: authentication, websphere, basic-authentication

I'm struggling with basic http authentication and I didn't find a solution yet. 
Here are my steps, please tell me where I'm wrong at:

- Create a new policy set
- Add HTTP transport policy to this set
- Create a new provider bindings
- Add HTTP transport and specify the username and password for the client (I don't know if this part is correct)
- Go to service provider and Attach the policy and binding to related service

And when I test my service with a .NET client(not at local), It behaves like there is no authentication. 
Am I missing sth ?

WAS version: 7.0.0.25

Thank you by now.
Emrah

Comment: Did you configure the service/servlet to user basic authentication ?

Comment: CAn you provide some more detail about your application? You may not need to use Policy Sets. Is it a Web Service? And, since you are using a .NET client, I am even more inclined to think you can just use the old WebSphere method of securing Web Resources. Can you post the Web.xml for your service?